# Редактирование скрипта

Tags: mysql, php, html, javascript, css

В данном скрипте реализована выборка данных из файлов посредством функции   `readfile($_GET['page'].'.php');`.

Вопрос:

1.Как изменить, что бы выборка шла из БД, что бы выбранная инфа из БД соответствовала странице?

2.Нужно, что бы в массиве $pages записи типа 'about'=>'О нас' были заменены на переменные, например `"link"=>"link_name"`, к тому же, они должны идти в цикле, что бы выбирались все строки из БД а не только первая.

```
 <?php
// массив в котором будем хранить допустимые имена файлов и их русские названия 
$pages=array(
'about'=>'О нас',
'contacts'=>'Контакты'
);

// определим если $_GET[page] пустая то выведем about
if($_GET['page']=='') $_GET['page']='about';

// если такой  страницы в меню нет то выведем содержимое файла txt/404.php (нужно    создать)
if(!array_key_exists ($_GET['page'],$pages))  $_GET['page']='404';
?> 
<html>
<title>
<?php
echo $pages[$_GET['page']]; // русское название в заголовке 
?>
</title>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td width="150">
<?php

// генерация меню
foreach($pages as $key=>$value) // цикл который обходит все пары ключ(индекс)-  значение массива $pages, на каждом шаге ключ будет записываться в $key а значение в   $value 
{

if($_GET['page']==$value) // пункт меню равен текущей странице, значит его не нужно  делать ссылкой
{
   echo $pages[$_GET['page']]; 
}
else 
{
  echo '<a href="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
     echo "<br />";
}

?>

</td>
<td>
<h1>
  <?php
 echo $pages[$_GET['page']];
  ?>
</h1>
<?php
   // функция readfile читает и выводит на экран содержимое файла            $_GET['page'].'.php'
 // имя файла в данном случае динамическое и состоит из пути и значения  переменной    полученной методом GET 
   readfile($_GET['page'].'.php');
 ?>
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я может не понимаю сути написаного скрипта. Но не ужели по проще нельзя было сделать?

```
<?php
function content($file){ 
   if(file_exists($file)) 
       include '$file'; 
   else 
       include '404.php';
}

$page = (!isset($_GET['page'])?'main':trim($_GET['page']));  
switch($page){
default: 
   $file = '404.php';
   $title = 'Not found 404';
break;
case 'main':
   $file = 'main.php';
   $title = 'Главная';
break;
case 'o_nas':
   $file = 'o_nas.php';
   $title = 'О себе';
break;
// ...
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title> <?php echo $title;?>  
</title></head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td style='width:150px;'> меню тут сами вручную напишите лучше</td><td> <h1><?php echo $title.'</h1>'; content($file);?></td> </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: файлы main.php, 404.php есть ?Я чуть под редактировал, пробуйте

Comment: $file = 'main.php';
$title = 'Главная' (тут как я понял надо ставить ;)
break;

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Писал на скорую руку.

Comment: у вас в папке, где находится сей скрипт есть файлы main.php и 404.php. Кстати лучше 404 ошибки использовать через .htacess

Comment: Почему то $title все время показывает надпись Главная

Comment: исправил))

Comment: Все отлично СПАСИБО !!!